# How to get changes from SP server 2010 in client object model?

Tags: development, changelog

Below is the code:

```
        ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://SPSite");
        context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pwd", "domain");
        ChangeQuery cq = new ChangeQuery(true, true);                  
        ChangeCollection col = list.GetChanges(cq);            
        context.Load(col);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
        MessageBox.Show(col.Count.ToString());
```

Irrespective of the changes done, it always shows 0.

Comment: Has your connecting user account got enough rights to actually see/read the data? Update; there seem to be others with the same problem, no solution mentioned: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/af9c6883-7781-4552-85fb-e840b5f55790

Comment: Yes, it has. Even I went through the link mentioned and felt the same as not to modify the stored procedure.

Comment: I agree on not modifying it. But in that case, I can't help you either. Sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://SPSite");
context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pwd", "domain");
ChangeQuery cq = new ChangeQuery(true, true);                
ChangeCollection col = list.GetChanges(cq);            
context.Load(col);
context.ExecuteQuery();
ChangeToken endToken;
foreach(Change change in col)
{
 endToken = change.ChangeToken;// endToken serves as next start token for further logs.
// Do your stuffs here.
}
```

This can be the appropriate solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://SPSite");
context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pwd", "domain");
ChangeQuery cq = new ChangeQuery(true, true); 
cq.ChangeTokenStart = new ChangeToken();
cq.ChangeTokenStart.StringValue = "1;3;" + list.Id.ToString() + ";" + DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1).Ticks.ToString() + ";-1";                 
ChangeCollection col = list.GetChanges(cq);            
context.Load(col);
context.ExecuteQuery();
MessageBox.Show(col.Count.ToString());
```

Even though I don't prefer creating token by yourself, this seems to be the only way which works as per my googling so far.