# How to get ChangeToken for the site specified in sharepoint client object model

Tags: sharepoint-online

```
ChangeCollection siteChanges = clientContext.Web.GetChanges(new ChangeQuery(true,true));
clientContext.Load(siteChanges);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

siteChanges.LastChangeToken; is not there as in Server object model(SPChangeCollection.LastChangeToken).
How do i get that?

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/47519/how-to-get-changes-from-sp-server-2010-in-client-object-model

The above link has the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The ChangeQuery class has the ChangeTokenEnd property:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.changequery.changetokenend.aspx

Comment: I tried that before posting. its giving null always. Any specific reason?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for an answer, you will need to set the value of the ChangeTokenEnd so that only changes up to this time will be returned in the query.